# Manipulate json, remove two items in a group by key value

Tags: json, jq

How can I manipulate this chunk of json:

```
{
"id": "whatever",
"attributes": [
    {
      "key": "this",
      "value": "A"
    },
    {
      "key": "that",
      "value": "B"
    },
    {
      "key": "other",
      "value": "C"
    }
  ]
}
```

So that it matches on "that" and removes the key and value both in that grouping, leaving json like this:

```
{
"id": "whatever",
"attributes": [
    {
      "key": "this",
      "value": "A"
    },
    {
      "key": "other",
      "value": "C"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am attempting to use jq on linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
.attributes |= map(select(.key != "that"))
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BWuBGRGS7o)

Comment: That works too, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
jq 'del(.attributes[] | select(.key == "that"))' test.json | sponge test.json
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).